# Find all the ideals of $\mathbb Q[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am trying to find all the ideals of the ring $\mathbb Q[X]$.

If $I$ is a non trivial ideal of $\mathbb Q[X]$, then there exists $p(x) \in \mathbb Q[X]$. Since $I$ is an ideal and a group under addition, we have that $-p(x) \in \mathbb Q[X]$ and $np(x) \in \mathbb Q[X]$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z$. I got stuck at this point, I would appreciate suggestions to find all the ideals of this ring.

Comment: You know it's an euclidean domain? So it's a PID too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstract hint: $\mathbb{K}$ field $\Rightarrow \mathbb{K}[x] $ is a PID. 
Concrete hint: $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is ED, so you can divide and you can look for a minimal polynomial.

Comment: I think I got it:  Let $I \subset Q[X]$ be an ideal such that $I \neq {0}$, then there is $p(x) \in I$, with $p \neq 0$. Consider $S \subset \mathbb N=\{n : n=deg(f), f \in I \setminus{0}\}$, then $S \neq \emptyset$ because $k=deg(p(x)) \in S$. So $S$ has a minimal element $m$. Consider $q$ the monic polynomial (I can suppose it is monic) such that $k=q(x)$. Then $I=<q(x)>$: let $f \in I$, then $f=q(x)s(x)+r(x)$ with $deg(r)<deg(q)$. Since $I$ is a group under addition, $f-qs=r \in I$. But then $r$ has to be $0$ by the hypothesis that $deg(q)=k$ is the minimal degree, this means $f=qs$.

Comment: That's the way.